# How to display recent ten posts of specific category when visiting that specific category's link/url

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

When i visit mysite.com/category/*** It only displays last post of that category.
But i want it to display recent ten posts of that category.

In short...
I want my site http://bishwash.com.np/category/entertainment/ to display posts like http://www.onlinekhabar.com/category/bichitra-world/

Answer (score 0):

you can get the recent posts with wp_recent_posts($arg,ARRAY_A );

```
 <?php $args = array(
'numberposts' => 10,
'offset' => 0,
'category' => 1,
'orderby' => 'post_date',
'order' => 'DESC',
'include' => ,
'exclude' => ,
'meta_key' => ,
'meta_value' =>,
'post_type' => 'post',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'suppress_filters' => true );

$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args, ARRAY_A );

?>
```

Comment: I'm bad at coding. In which page should i add this... or do you know any WP plugin for this? @user3040610

Comment: where should i put that [shortcode]? is /category/entertainment/ a REAL page? i can't find it anywhere, where is it located? @user3040610

Comment: that's what i'm talking about. where is my entertainment page? @user3040610

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Default_Usage) to retrieve posts.

```
    <ul>
        <?php
            global $post;
            $myposts = get_posts('numberposts=5&category=1');
            foreach($myposts as $post) :
        ?>
        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
```

Change `category=1` to your category ID number.If you to get post from `XYZ` category and `XYZ` category had `13` ID number then it would be something like this `category=13`.

Comment: I'm bad at coding. In which page should i add this... or do you know any WP plugin for this?

Comment: There are so many plugins like : [
Special Recent Posts
](https://wordpress.org/plugins/special-recent-posts/), [Flexible Recent Post](https://wordpress.org/plugins/flexible-recent-posts/) and more.You can search on google as well.

Comment: And if you want to do it with the code, you can place above code where other posts are retrieving.But for that you need to find the file from where that posts are coming.And in that file you can use above code by wrapping it in a condition `if(is_category( '9' )) {}`.

Comment: My guess is that, it should be in a file called `content.php`.Search for that file in your theme.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6q2LZs2ooh3UHdGTzljNzMyRUU/view?usp=sharing please add your code there. i couldn't figure out. @Rohil_PHPBeginner

Answer (score 0):

In categroy.php page before

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

//paste the following code

$catID = the_category_ID();
$args = array( 'numberposts' => '10','category' => $catID);
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
setup_postdata($recent_posts);
```

At the end of loop

```
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Answer (score 0):

The number of posts is set globally for all index type pages (including the home page and archives and category) in settings, reading

It seems you have limited it to 1 ? Then it's better design to set it to 10 because that will apply to all pages, and design a specific template for the home page, where you limit the number of posts with the methods given to to.

You can achieve that in two ways : 
- build a page template, with a specific query, create a page with this template, and define it as homepage in settings -> reading
- create a home.php file in your theme

In both cases, it's better to have a child theme, not to loose modifications when your theme is updated.

Comment: Actually my concern is not no. of posts, it's disappearing of social buttons on /category/*** pages. Setting reading to 10... displayed full contents of 1 post & summary of other 9 posts. The social buttons didn't appear on that 1 post. So how can i make that '1 post' appear as summary too (just like second site in first thread), so that visitors will click that 1 post's link and will be able to see social buttons in the next page. (i.e. social buttons appears on mysite.com/post-title/) @Lumiere de Lune

Comment: You should reformulate your question then, because it's totally different, and the answer depends on how you display the social buttons on single post (plugin ? which one ? through own code on single.php ?)

Comment: addthis dot com's plugin. like all other plugins it gives options to insert btns on page/post. but i don't have REAL /category/*** page. @Lumiere de Lune

Answer (score 0):

Create the template (`sample.php`) and write code like

```
$catquery = new WP_Query( 'cat=3&posts_per_page=10' );
```

or use `CATEGORYNAME`

Note: When we click the link it redirects to to the `sample.php` and the category name is dynamic that means when we click the category its automatically stored to the `CATEGORYNAME`

Comment: i have four categories at the moment. should i create four templates? like entertainment.php, health.php, etc? entertainment.php: `$catquery = new WP_Query( 'entertainment'&posts_per_page=10' );` will this work? @sankar

Comment: no.you dont need to add 4 templates.You should customize the archive.php to get required results